# How to process multiple api requests in one

Tags: javascript, json, get, xmlhttprequest, put

For example I have some_website/a.json which contains:

```
{"test":"1","test2":"2"}
```

and some_website/b.json which contains:

```
{"test":"3","test2":"4"}
```

how i can GET and PUT this values in some_website/c.json using XMLHttpRequest like

```
{"testing1":{"test":"1","test2":"2"},"testing2":{"test":"3","test2":"4"}}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague on how your use case looks like. I think your chances on finding a results are higher if you follow this recommendation: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not natively possible. There are techniques like “Batch Requests”. Facebook implemented them in their API, for example.
[Facebook Batch Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/)